# Re-Ranking Algorithm for Anonymous Users

Tags: sorting, recommendation-engine, personalization, amazon-personalize

I have a website:

1. 10,000 pages, each page represent a category, for example: "Laptops".
2. On each page I am showing 20 recommended products
3. 99% of the users are anonymous
4. For each user I have a context (device, user-agent and category)
5. For each product I have the price and the seller name
6. I have 2 events: outbound & purchase

I would like to re-rank (re-order, sort) the results for each new anonymous user based on the user context. I would like to re-rank based on performance (outbound & purchase).

Do you have recommendation for Specific algorithm OR tool OR service to do that? I found AWS Personalize very nice but the problem is that all of my users are anonymous so I don't believe it can be effective in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Personalize can still be used effectively when most/all users are anonymous. If you track users as visitors using a cookie or local storage, then a visitor's session ID can be considered the `userId` in Personalize. You will lose the continuity of stitching together the same logical user's activity across multiple sessions but you can still get in-session personalization. This requires calling [PutEvents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/recording-events.html) with the visitor's session ID in the `sessionId` field and **excluding** the `userId` field. Then when calling the [GetRecommendations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/API_RS_GetRecommendations.html) or [GetPersonalizedRanking](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/API_RS_GetPersonalizedRanking.html) APIs, use the visitor's session ID as the `userId` field. Personalize will consider the event activity for the visitor's session when providing recommendations or reranking items.

If the visitor is a known user or later becomes known (i.e. signs in or creates an account), then pass their user ID in the `userId` field for `PutEvents` and `GetRecommendations`/`GetPersonalizedRanking`. At the next training, Personalize will associate any prior anonymous events (i.e. those with a `sessionId` but not a `userId`) to the user. The key is using a consistent `sessionId` across the anonymous and known events for the user for the session.